# If statement doesn't work for table view Cells properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating app which is using `Core Data` and `UITableViewControllers`to display a list of [MELs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_minimum_equipment_list).

I've done everything but I cannot get along with checking `UITableViewCell` should be editable or not.
Here is the screenshot of my app which should help you imagine my problem:

[image]

I'm checking whether `chapter` has any sections. If this is true it is displaying everything in black, if not the `detailTextLabel` color is changed to red. But as you can see, some Cells are colored even if they have some sections. How is it possible?

Here is my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Initializing Cell and filling it with info
    Chapter *chapter = [self.MELs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number: %@ \t Sections: %lu", chapter.number, (unsigned long)[chapter.sections count]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [chapter.title capitalizedString];

    if ([chapter.sections count] == 0) {
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as cells are reused you have to reset the textcolor to default if the condition is not met:

```
if ([chapter.sections count] == 0) {
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} else {
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Comment: @Cojoj You can go with Jonathan Solution Or you can pass nil in place of cell identifier ;                                              UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @Anuj using nil as identifier might lead to no caching at all, i dont think this it wath you should do in tables.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

`[cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];` is saved in the reusable cell. If you add an extra `CellIdentifier` for the 'red' cells, the problem is solved.

Additionally. you should check if the retrieved cell for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` return `nil`;

Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initializing Cell and filling it with info
    Chapter *chapter = [self.MELs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if ([chapter.sections count] == 0) {
        CellIdentifier = @"Cell-red";
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
            // Cell properties
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if ([CellIdentifier isEqual:@"Cell-red"]) {
                [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            }
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number: %@ \t Sections: %lu", chapter.number, (unsigned long)[chapter.sections count]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [chapter.title capitalizedString];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row % 2)// Change this according to your requirement
    {
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```